# NodeRed crashed: TypeError: binary is not a function at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

My Node-red recently started crashing, following is the stacktrace:

```
TypeError: binary is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/nodes/core/core/75-exec.js:135:46
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Comment: Look here, and consider updating your NodeJS: https://github.com/sindresorhus/alfred-emoj/issues/9

Comment: What version of NodeJS and Node-RED are you running?